# Как передать относительные url в $.ajax в yii2?

Tags: javascript, yii

Если я нахожусь на главной странице и оттуда добавляю товар в корзину ajax запросом отправляю на сервер данные - то срабатывает такой вариант:

```
`$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        qty = $('#qty').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: './cart/add',
       // url: "'.\yii\helpers\Url::to(['/cart/add', 'id' => $product->id]).'",
       //  url: "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['cart/add').'",
        data: {id: id, qty: qty},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res){
            if(!res) alert('Ошибка!');
            showCart(res);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
});`
```

При  это url или url: './cart/add' или url: 'cart/add'. Когда я с другой страницы пытаюсь добавить товар в корзину, в частности со страницы товара, срабатывает url такой url: '../cart/add'. Как мне настроить единый url для ajax запроса с любой страницы сайта?

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
url: './cart/add'
```

На

```
url: '/cart/add',
```

Comment: Заменить пробовала - не работает

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали решение на форуме YII2

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        qty = $('#qty').val(),
        url = e.currentTarget.href; // Линк берем из ссылки

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {id: id, qty: qty},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res){
            if(!res) alert('Ошибка!');
            showCart(res);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
});
```